# Difference between virtual memory consumption and real memory with Memory Monitor on iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments, virtual-memory

I am stuck with an issue in my app. I have been testing up until now mostly on my iPad 3 with occasional checks on my iPad 1 to make sure all is well.

I am playing a UIImageView animation in my app and it keeps quitting with only a "Received memory warning" message before it quits.

I have been using the Object Allocations tool in instruments but according to that, my memory usage is way low. So after researching for a bit I came across this post by Mr. Larson: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627221/329900

Now I am using the Memory Monitor tool instead. However, I don't understand why I am quitting. The 1st gen. iPad has 256MB of ram. Now I know I can't use all of that...some say you shouldn't use more than 100MB.

Is that real memory though, or virtual memory...or maybe some combination? My real memory is consistently between 20 - 25MB but the virtual is around 190 - 205MB when it crashes.

Here's a screenshot:[image]

Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Comment: I suggest running the application with the VM Tracker instrument enabled. The VM Tracker shows graphics memory usage (virtual memory). Most probably your UIImageView animation is loading too many images in memory to perform the animation. A more efficient animation technique would be appropriate.

Comment: So what options do I have for a more efficient animation technique? Also, does VM Tracker show me if I'm loading to many images at once?

Answer (score 6):

The WWDC (Session 242) video found by searching for *iOS App Performance: Memory* in the [WWDC 2012 Session Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) page will give you a better understanding of the difference between VM and real memory.

But here is a quick overview:
A pointer Range = 2^32 = 4GB This is larger then the physical memory on any device(apple has shipped). This is done by taking all available space and dividing it up into 4kb chunks. Not all the memory your application can access is in physical memory at the same time. These 4kb chunks are call pages. Your allocations get split out of larger chunks of virtual memory. Then these virtual memory objects get mapped to physical memory.

Comment: +1. That is an awesome video which should be required viewing before using the memory tools.

Comment: I watched the video and I think I am getting it, but I don't understand still how to figure out if my app is indeed loading too much at once.

Comment: Isn't there some safer or better way to determine if the app is loading too much at once than just to make sure it isn't quitting?

Comment: You will get a low memory warning if you are loading too much. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9461490/1144161. Make sure you are making use of didReceiveMemoryWarning.