# most representative allocations metric for checking app memory usage

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, instruments, allocation

Recently I have been using Xcode instruments allocation to profile the memory usage of my app. There are a number of metrics, for example the heapshot analysis and live bytes amongst others. Which of these metrics is the most representative for testing app memory usage and why.

Comment: The VM Tracker instrument is most helpful to get an idea of how much memory is used and when to expect memory notifications. Here's some information that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461490/using-instruments-to-work-through-low-memory-warnings/9463343#9463343